# What is a Turing point?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling

What is "*the **Turing point** associated with the bifurcation of spatially uniform solutions"*?

I'm primarily concerned with what a Turing point is - Google is convinced that I mean a *turning* point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the stability analysis of homogeneous steady state solutions to a system of reaction-diffusion equations. The point (in parameter space) where such an homogeneous steady state becomes unstable with respect to a spatially periodic perturbations, is called a Turing point, because the bifurcation in question is called a *Turing bifurcation* -- which is the term I would advise Googling (Googleing? To Google).